# What's the best way to pass a String as a separate type?

Tags: java

I want to create a method like `example` below to make sure that a user is only able to provide a value that corresponds to one of the constants defined in the `Name` class:

```
public class Name{
 public static String JOHN = "John";
 public static String MARY = "Mary";
 public static String TAB = "\t";
}

public void example(Name name){
 test(name);
}

public void test(String name){
 System.out.println(name);
}
```

Basically the `example` method just takes a `String` argument. But I want to restrict the types of Strings that could be passed by the user so if I make the parameter `String name` it will be open to any type of input.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Who would name their child "\t"?

Comment: Someone with too much S.O. karma?

Comment: A couple were told they could not name their child 4Real (it has a digit) so the child is officially called "Superman", but his family call him "4Real". http://www.nzherald.co.nz/lifestyle/news/article.cfm?c_id=6&objectid=10456528 Why they didn't make it Forreal I don't know. ;)

Comment: Who would name their child "\t" when they could name him `Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--` you mean? Or [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) to his friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an enum:

```
public enum Name {
  John, Mary
}
public void example(Name name){
  test(name);
}
```

You can also add methods, state, and constructors to your enum as well:

```
public enum Name {
  John(23), Mary(20)

  private int age;

  private Name(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }

  public int getAge() {
    return age;
  }
}
```

I find I do that kind of thing a lot.

Since I see you've now added the TAB one, how about this:

```
public enum Name {
  JOHN("John"), Mary("Mary"), TAB("\n")

  private int str;

  private Name(int str) {
    this.str = str;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return str;
  }
}
```

Comment: ditto copy .. :| what were we thinking .. :p

Comment: Not everyone with the name might be that age ;), but a good example of using an attribute.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey, good point, actually I was going to use string example but then decided to mix it up and use an int, because in this case, the enum's toString will be good enough.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: I guess it depends on whether John and Mary here refer to specific people or the class of all Johns and Marys...

Comment: The age could be how old the name is... ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use an enum?

```
public enum Name{
 John, Mary;
}

public void test(Name name){
 System.out.println(name);
}
```

Its a bad idea to mix concepts, TAB is clearly not a person's name. However, if the example were different you can do this.

```
public enum Name{
 John, Mary, 
 TAB { public String toString() { return "\n"; } };
}
```

Comment: My example of John and Mary was bad because I actually wanted to create a class that represents different "special characters" - "\n", "\t", "\r", etc. So in that case, it seems that using a constructor that takes a `String` argument (as dgrant has done below with ints) might be the way to go, rather than adding these bracketed `toString` methods as you have done here. What do you think?

Comment: It depends on whether you want any String to be allowed or only certain strings.  You can also have two methods, one which takes names and the other only takes special characters.

Answer (score 0):

Strings cannot be subclassed, hence you cannot immediately do what you want to.

Either consider using ENUM's, or explicitly test the passed string for valid values in the constructor, and throw a RuntimeException if it is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code has an error because you are passing the object called
    name
that is of type
    Name
into example but into test you are getting a String and it is getting passed name from example so I'm not sure what you are trying to do.
Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use ENUM?

```
public enum Name{
    John, Marry
}
```

and then you can write method like

```
public void example (Name name){
    test(name);
}
```